# What Does this mean in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server 2005, and when I execute this query:

```
select 
    F.E,
    S.E 
from 
    Subject
```

I get these errors:

> The multi-part identifier "F.E" could not be bound. 
>   The multi-part identifier "S.E" could not be bound.

but when execute this query, it works fine

```
select * from Subject
```

What do these errors mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error means that the SQL server doesn't know what `F.E` and `S.E` is.

If `S` refers to your `Subject` table, for instace, you need to assign the name `S`:

```
SELECT S.* FROM Subject S
```

That will fetch all fields (`*`) in all rows (lack of `WHERE`) from the table `Subject` which is temporarily called `S`.

If you want to fetch only the field `E` from `Subject`, you could write

```
SELECT S.E FROM Subject S
```

This is the exact same as writing

```
SELECT E FROM Subject
```

Comment: I think the problem is that he use F.E and S.E as column name. Which is why he tries to use it. Dot is only allowed if you put column name in brackets. Like `SELECT [F.E],[S.E] FROM Subject`.

Comment: @MadBoy: that could very well be the case. OP doesn't give us many clues :)

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `F` and the `S` aliases are unknown.

```
select S.E
    from Subject S
```

You then define the alias `S`

**EDIT #1**

If you want to use those special characters, you have to use quoted identifiers.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

select [F.E]
        , [S.E]
    from Subject
```

You could even have field names that include the space character.

```
[Postal Address]
[Family Name]
[Is Active?]
[Subject #]
[And So Forth!...]
```

These are some simple examples. =)

Comment: Simple examples of terrible things. I'm not sure anybody is better off knowing this :)

Comment: @David: Agreed! I dislike the use of quoted identifier. I better stick to the good old fashion, either CamelCasing (SQL Server) or underlined separator (Oracle). =)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your stack over flow just name it as F_E not F.E

It is an identifier it doesn't have symbols like `.!@#$#$%^%^&&*&()`
but it can have `_`

Comment: @alex: grab a coffee before you comment, please. we try not to use that tone at SO. I think he meant to say that he solved the problem by renaming the fields...? In which case the error message was exactly the way that he wrote it, at the time that he received it.